# Deploying HawtIO to WildFly 8.0.0 fails

Tags: wildfly, hawtio, wildfly-8

I have had HawtIO running under JBoss AS 7.1.1 but when I try to deploy to WildFly 8.0.0 it fails with the following

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @Default
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.sonatype.guice.bean.binders.TypeConverterMap.injector
```

and

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @
Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Inject org.sonatype.guice.bean.l
ocators.DefaultBeanLocator.autoPublish(Injector)
```

I have tried various version of HawtIO (1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0) with WildFly 8.0.0 and 8.1.0CR and have had no luck so far. All version of HawtIO worked with JBoss AS 7.1.1 so I am guessing the issue is with WildFly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have anything else in wildfly? and do you deply hawtio-default or hawtio-offline as a WAR file? And just by copying that WAR to the deploy folder or how do you deploy it?

And there is also a --no-slf4j.war you can try that has no logger. I think some containers had some problems with that etc.

It does smell like a sonartype JAR that hawtio has embedded in the web-inf/lib that wildfly barfs. Maybe its fixed in a newer sonartype JAR, or some way to turn that CDI scanning off in wildfly. We do not use CDI in hawtio.

Comment: I did have some other applications in Wildfly at one point but I have since created the .skipdeploy marker file for them and cleared the tmp directory. 

For hawtio I am using the 1.4.0 default jar but had the same issue with previous versions.

I will try a clean install of Wildfly and the --no-slf4j.war and post and update here.

Comment: Oh didnt know about a .skipdeploy. Do you by any chance have a link to where I can read more about that functionality?

Comment: Using the no-slf4j.war seems to have solved the issue.

Thanks for the help.

As for the deployment marker files, check this out https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Application+deployment#Applicationdeployment-MarkerFiles .

Comment: Sorry I just noticed that link was to the JBoss AS docs, but to be accurate the link for the content under Wildfly is https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide.